# MDX: how to collapse multiple values in a dimention into one?

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, olap

I am building an SSRS report over an OLAP cube that breaks the data down by currency. Currencies go into columns. The twist is that the users want to see only a couple of major currencies (like USD, EUR, JPY) and have everything else combined into "other" column.

Effectively, I need to collapse the whole universe of currencies into USD, EUR, JPY and Other. What is the best way to achieve it? I feel this should be doable, but I can't find the right keywords for google search.

Comment: Are you handling the problem of currency-conversion separately? That is, the measure that you are using is normalized so you can safely aggregate the values in the "Other" column, and you won't be adding different currency values together? Or is your question about how to do currency conversion?

Comment: No, no currency conversions, the values are supposed to be normalized. On the other hand, it would not hurt to double check that I am not adding Russian roubles to Brazilian reals. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a measure that can safely be combined into an "Other" group, you could combine multiple members by creating a set of the "Major" members and a new "Other" member which is the aggregate of all members with the "Major" ones removed.

Here's an example against Adventure Works:

```
WITH 
    SET [Major] AS {
        [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].&[100], 
        [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].&[19],
        [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].&[98]
        }
    MEMBER [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[Other] AS 
        Aggregate(Except([Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[Source Currency Code], [Major]))
SELECT
    {[Major], [Other]} ON 0,
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
```

Results:

```
                          USD            CAD            GBP          Other
Australia           $9,012.50         (null)         (null)  $9,051,988.08 
Canada            $172,181.96  $1,805,662.90         (null)         (null)
France          $2,462,361.69         (null)      $1,084.33    $180,571.69 
Germany         $2,656,527.35         (null)         (null)    $237,784.99 
United Kingdom      $4,446.85         (null)  $3,387,265.36         (null)
United States   $9,388,934.97        $854.54         (null)         (null)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I needed. Just in case, the original query had a cross-join, so instead of {[Major], [Other]} ON 1 I had to do { dimension1.ALLMEMBERS * dimension2.ALLMEMBERS * ([Major] + [Other]) }